# Flutter Search module is not showing filter

Tags: flutter, search

I'm creating a `search` module but it is not working. When I try to search keyword, the users are not showing. Kindly take a look on it what I'm missing in my code. Thanks.

Here is how my screen is looking

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7jxp.jpg)

Here is my code of this page

```
class CategoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int categoryId;

  List<Data> list = [];

  CategoryPage({Key? key, required this.list, required this.categoryId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CategoryPage> createState() => _CategoryPageState();
}

class _CategoryPageState extends State<CategoryPage> {
  late CategoryDetailService categoryDetailService;
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  List<UserData> user = [];
  bool isCalled = false;
  String categoryID = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    categoryID = widget.categoryId.toString();
  }

  void searchUser(String query) {
    final suggestions = user.where((element) {
      final userName = element.firstName!.toLowerCase();
      final input = query.toLowerCase();
      return userName.contains(input);
    }).toList();
    setState(() => user = suggestions);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!isCalled) {
      isCalled = true;
      categoryDetailService = Provider.of<CategoryDetailService>(context);
      categoryDetailService.offSet = 1;
      (categoryDetailService.data ?? []).clear();
      categoryDetailService.fetchData(context, categoryID);
    }
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: widget.list.length,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                leading: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded,
                    size: Dimensions.height30,
                    color: AppColors.fIconsAndTextColor,
                  ),
                ),
                actions: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: Dimensions.height15),
                    child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () => pushNewScreen(context, screen: const NotificationScreen()),
                        child: ImageIcon(
                          const AssetImage('assets/images/notif.png'),
                          size: Dimensions.height40,
                          color: AppColors.fIconsAndTextColor,
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
                elevation: 0.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
            body: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.width15),
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: Dimensions.height45,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.radius10),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          blurRadius: Dimensions.radius10,
                          offset: const Offset(0.0, 6),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: controller,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      onChanged: searchUser,
                      cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                      autocorrect: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: LanguageStringKeys.instance.search.tr,
                        isDense: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                          Dimensions.width10,
                          Dimensions.height20,
                          Dimensions.width10,
                          0,
                        ),
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        suffixIcon: InkWell(
                          onTap: () => pushNewScreen(context, screen: const FilterScreen()),
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.tune,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 0,
                            style: BorderStyle.none,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height10),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: Dimensions.width15,
                    top: Dimensions.height15,
                    right: Dimensions.width15,
                  ),
                  child: SmallText(
                    text: LanguageStringKeys.instance.category.tr,
                  ),
                ),
                // SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height10),
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: widget.list
                        .map((e) => InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                categoryDetailService.offSet = 1;
                                (categoryDetailService.data ?? []).clear();
                                categoryDetailService.fetchData(context, e.id.toString());
                              },
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.height10 - 2),
                                child: Tab(
                                  height: Dimensions.height70,
                                  child: TabsContainer(
                                    image: e.photo ?? "",
                                    tittle: Get.put(AppController()).isEnglish() ? e.enName ?? "" : e.arName ?? "",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
                UsersCategoryPage(categoryDetailService.usersByFilter?.data ?? []),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the model of my users

```
UsersByFilter usersByFilterFromJson(String str) => UsersByFilter.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String usersByFilterToJson(UsersByFilter data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class UsersByFilter {
  UsersByFilter({
    this.total,
    this.perPage,
    this.currentPage,
    this.lastPage,
    this.nextPageUrl,
    this.prevPageUrl,
    this.from,
    this.to,
    this.success,
    this.enMessage,
    this.arMessage,
    this.data,
    this.status,
  });

  UsersByFilter.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    total = json['total'];
    perPage = json['per_page'].toString();
    currentPage = json['current_page'].toString();
    lastPage = json['last_page'];
    nextPageUrl = json['next_page_url'];
    prevPageUrl = json['prev_page_url'];
    from = json['from'].toString();
    to = json['to'].toString();
    success = json['success'];
    enMessage = json['en_message'];
    arMessage = json['ar_message'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = [];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data?.add(UserData.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    status = json['status'];
  }

  int? total;
  String? perPage;
  String? currentPage;
  int? lastPage;
  String? nextPageUrl;
  String? prevPageUrl;
  String? from;
  String? to;
  bool? success;
  String? enMessage;
  String? arMessage;
  List<UserData>? data;
  int? status;

  UsersByFilter copyWith({
    int? total,
    String? perPage,
    String? currentPage,
    int? lastPage,
    String? nextPageUrl,
    String? prevPageUrl,
    String? from,
    String? to,
    bool? success,
    String? enMessage,
    String? arMessage,
    List<UserData>? data,
    int? status,
  }) =>
      UsersByFilter(
        total: total ?? this.total,
        perPage: perPage ?? this.perPage,
        currentPage: currentPage ?? this.currentPage,
        lastPage: lastPage ?? this.lastPage,
        nextPageUrl: nextPageUrl ?? this.nextPageUrl,
        prevPageUrl: prevPageUrl ?? this.prevPageUrl,
        from: from ?? this.from,
        to: to ?? this.to,
        success: success ?? this.success,
        enMessage: enMessage ?? this.enMessage,
        arMessage: arMessage ?? this.arMessage,
        data: data ?? this.data,
        status: status ?? this.status,
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['total'] = total;
    map['per_page'] = perPage;
    map['current_page'] = currentPage;
    map['last_page'] = lastPage;
    map['next_page_url'] = nextPageUrl;
    map['prev_page_url'] = prevPageUrl;
    map['from'] = from;
    map['to'] = to;
    map['success'] = success;
    map['en_message'] = enMessage;
    map['ar_message'] = arMessage;
    if (data != null) {
      map['data'] = data?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    map['status'] = status;
    return map;
  }
}


UserData dataFromJson(String str) => UserData.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String dataToJson(UserData data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class UserData {
  UserData({
    this.id,
    this.username,
    this.type,
    this.customerId,
    this.lang,
    this.countryId,
    this.email,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.phone,
    this.address,
    this.location,
    this.dob,
    this.sex,
    this.city,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.idPhoto,
    this.accessToken,
    this.accessTokenEnd,
    this.roleId,
    this.verified,
    this.verificationCode,
    this.passwordCode,
    this.fcmToken,
    this.mobile,
    this.bio,
    this.photo,
    this.lat,
    this.lon,
    this.verifiedSponsor,
    this.requests,
    this.isActive,
    this.categoryId,
    this.companyName,
    this.tradeLicense,
    this.field,
    this.workTime,
    this.facebook,
    this.linkedIn,
    this.instagram,
    this.whatsApp,
    this.wishlisted,
    this.fbId,
    this.googleToken,
    this.facebookToken,
    this.facebookId,
    this.googleId,
    this.balance,
    this.photos,
    this.role,
  });

  UserData.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    id = json['id'];
    username = json['username'];
    type = json['type'];
    customerId = json['customer_id'];
    lang = json['lang'];
    countryId = json['country_id'];
    email = json['email'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    phone = json['phone'];
    address = json['address'];
    location = json['location'];
    dob = json['dob'];
    sex = json['sex'];
    city = json['city'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    idPhoto = json['id_photo'];
    accessToken = json['access_token'];
    accessTokenEnd = json['access_token_end'];
    roleId = json['role_id'];
    verified = json['verified'];
    verificationCode = json['verification_code'];
    passwordCode = json['password_code'];
    fcmToken = json['fcm_token'];
    mobile = json['mobile'];
    bio = json['bio'];
    photo = json['photo'];
    lat = json['lat'];
    lon = json['lon'];
    verifiedSponsor = json['verified_sponsor'];
    requests = json['requests'];
    isActive = json['is_active'];
    categoryId = json['category_id'];
    companyName = json['company_name'];
    tradeLicense = json['trade_license'];
    field = json['field'];
    workTime = json['work_time'];
    facebook=
    json["facebook"];
    linkedIn=
    json["linkedIn"];
    instagram=
    json["instagram"];
    whatsApp=
    json["whatsApp"];
    wishlisted=
    json["wishlisted"];
    fbId=
    json["fb_id"];
    googleToken=
    json["google_token"];
    facebookToken=
    json["facebook_token"];
    facebookId=
    json["facebook_id"];
    googleId=
    json["google_id"];
    if (json['balance'] != null) {
      balance = [];
      json['balance'].forEach((v) {
        balance?.add(Balance.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['photos'] != null) {
      photos = [];
      json['photos'].forEach((v) {
        photos?.add(v);
      });
    }
    role = json['role'] != null ? Role.fromJson(json['role']) : null;
  }

  int? id;
  String? username;
  int? type;
  int? customerId;
  int? lang;
  int? countryId;
  String? email;
  String? firstName;
  dynamic lastName;
  String? phone;
  String? address;
  dynamic location;
  dynamic dob;
  dynamic sex;
  dynamic city;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  dynamic idPhoto;
  dynamic accessToken;
  dynamic accessTokenEnd;
  int? roleId;
  int? verified;
  String? verificationCode;
  String? passwordCode;
  String? fcmToken;
  String? mobile;
  String? bio;
  String? photo;
  String? lat;
  String? lon;
  int? verifiedSponsor;
  int? requests;
  int? isActive;
  String? categoryId;
  dynamic companyName;
  dynamic tradeLicense;
  dynamic field;
  dynamic workTime;
  String? facebook;
  String? linkedIn;
  String? instagram;
  String? whatsApp;
  bool? wishlisted;
  dynamic fbId;
  dynamic googleToken;
  dynamic facebookToken;
  dynamic facebookId;
  dynamic googleId;
  List<Balance>? balance;
  List<dynamic>? photos;
  Role? role;

  UserData copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? username,
    int? type,
    int? customerId,
    int? lang,
    int? countryId,
    String? email,
    String? firstName,
    dynamic lastName,
    String? phone,
    String? address,
    dynamic location,
    dynamic dob,
    dynamic sex,
    dynamic city,
    String? createdAt,
    String? updatedAt,
    dynamic idPhoto,
    dynamic accessToken,
    dynamic accessTokenEnd,
    int? roleId,
    int? verified,
    String? verificationCode,
    String? passwordCode,
    dynamic fcmToken,
    String? mobile,
    dynamic bio,
    dynamic photo,
    dynamic lat,
    dynamic lon,
    int? verifiedSponsor,
    int? requests,
    int? isActive,
    String? categoryId,
    dynamic companyName,
    dynamic tradeLicense,
    dynamic field,
    dynamic workTime,
    String? facebook,
    String? linkedIn,
    String? instagram,
    String? whatsApp,
    bool? wishlisted,
    dynamic fbId,
    dynamic googleToken,
    dynamic facebookToken,
    dynamic facebookId,
    dynamic googleId,
    List<Balance>? balance,
    List<dynamic>? photos,
    Role? role,
  }) =>
      UserData(
        id: id ?? this.id,
        username: username ?? this.username,
        type: type ?? this.type,
        customerId: customerId ?? this.customerId,
        lang: lang ?? this.lang,
        countryId: countryId ?? this.countryId,
        email: email ?? this.email,
        firstName: firstName ?? this.firstName,
        lastName: lastName ?? this.lastName,
        phone: phone ?? this.phone,
        address: address ?? this.address,
        location: location ?? this.location,
        dob: dob ?? this.dob,
        sex: sex ?? this.sex,
        city: city ?? this.city,
        createdAt: createdAt ?? this.createdAt,
        updatedAt: updatedAt ?? this.updatedAt,
        idPhoto: idPhoto ?? this.idPhoto,
        accessToken: accessToken ?? this.accessToken,
        accessTokenEnd: accessTokenEnd ?? this.accessTokenEnd,
        roleId: roleId ?? this.roleId,
        verified: verified ?? this.verified,
        verificationCode: verificationCode ?? this.verificationCode,
        passwordCode: passwordCode ?? this.passwordCode,
        fcmToken: fcmToken ?? this.fcmToken,
        mobile: mobile ?? this.mobile,
        bio: bio ?? this.bio,
        photo: photo ?? this.photo,
        lat: lat ?? this.lat,
        lon: lon ?? this.lon,
        verifiedSponsor: verifiedSponsor ?? this.verifiedSponsor,
        requests: requests ?? this.requests,
        isActive: isActive ?? this.isActive,
        categoryId: categoryId ?? this.categoryId,
        companyName: companyName ?? this.companyName,
        tradeLicense: tradeLicense ?? this.tradeLicense,
        field: field ?? this.field,
        workTime: workTime ?? this.workTime,
        facebook: facebook ?? this.facebook,
        linkedIn: linkedIn ?? this.linkedIn,
        instagram: instagram ?? this.instagram,
        whatsApp: whatsApp ?? this.whatsApp,
        wishlisted: wishlisted ?? this.wishlisted,
        fbId: fbId ?? this.fbId,
        googleToken: googleToken ?? this.googleToken,
        facebookToken: facebookToken ?? this.facebookToken,
        facebookId: facebookId ?? this.facebookId,
        googleId: googleId ?? this.googleId,
        balance: balance ?? this.balance,
        photos: photos ?? this.photos,
        role: role ?? this.role,
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['id'] = id;
    map['username'] = username;
    map['type'] = type;
    map['customer_id'] = customerId;
    map['lang'] = lang;
    map['country_id'] = countryId;
    map['email'] = email;
    map['first_name'] = firstName;
    map['last_name'] = lastName;
    map['phone'] = phone;
    map['address'] = address;
    map['location'] = location;
    map['dob'] = dob;
    map['sex'] = sex;
    map['city'] = city;
    map['created_at'] = createdAt;
    map['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    map['id_photo'] = idPhoto;
    map['access_token'] = accessToken;
    map['access_token_end'] = accessTokenEnd;
    map['role_id'] = roleId;
    map['verified'] = verified;
    map['verification_code'] = verificationCode;
    map['password_code'] = passwordCode;
    map['fcm_token'] = fcmToken;
    map['mobile'] = mobile;
    map['bio'] = bio;
    map['photo'] = photo;
    map['lat'] = lat;
    map['lon'] = lon;
    map['verified_sponsor'] = verifiedSponsor;
    map['requests'] = requests;
    map['is_active'] = isActive;
    map['category_id'] = categoryId;
    map['company_name'] = companyName;
    map['trade_license'] = tradeLicense;
    map['field'] = field;
    map['work_time'] = workTime;
    map['facebook'] = facebook;
    map['linkedIn'] = linkedIn;
    map['instagram'] = instagram;
    map['whatsApp'] = whatsApp;
    map['fb_id'] = fbId;
    map['google_token'] = googleToken;
    map['facebook_token'] = facebookToken;
    map['facebook_id'] = facebookId;
    map['google_id'] = googleId;
    if (balance != null) {
      map['balance'] = balance?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (photos != null) {
      map['photos'] = photos?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (role != null) {
      map['role'] = role?.toJson();
    }
    return map;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only rendering a list that gets loaded from the constructor better if you maintain a dummy list in a screen as you have mentioned somewhat **user**

```
    @override
          void initState() {

            user.addAll(widget.list)
            super.initState();
            categoryID = widget.categoryId.toString();
          }

 

    void searchUser(String query) {
    
    if(query.isNotEmpty){
    
        final suggestions = user.where((element) {
          final userName = element.firstName!.toLowerCase();
          final input = query.toLowerCase();
          return userName.contains(input);
        }).toList();
        setState(() => user = suggestions);
          }else{
        user.clear()
        user.addAll(widget.list)
         }

    }





SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: user.toList()
                        .map((e) => InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                categoryDetailService.offSet = 1;
                                (categoryDetailService.data ?? []).clear();
                                categoryDetailService.fetchData(context, e.id.toString());
                              },
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.height10 - 2),
                                child: Tab(
                                  height: Dimensions.height70,
                                  child: TabsContainer(
                                    image: e.photo ?? "",
                                    tittle: Get.put(AppController()).isEnglish() ? e.enName ?? "" : e.arName ?? "",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: I've mentioned my code, how can I accomplish my way? Your code is not working

Comment: I have just posted a code that needs to be replaced you better try with it. you need to maintain two lists one for the original and the other for filter and search purposes. You have the proper search function, but it will not affect the UI because of its wrong usage. you are using the constructor-based list in UI which is always constant.

Comment: Have you seen my screen?

Comment: there is only tab list rendering from constructor.